# PNG coloration issue CSS/HTML

Tags: image, opacity

I've got the weirdest thing happening with a PNG that has a partially opaque drop shadow beneath it. When I put it on top of a background image the coloration of the drop shadow changes substantially. I've listed 2 examples below. Does anyone with more experience than I think this is a CSS issue? I don't know enough about color opacity to know anything.

Here's a link to the image on a white background looking how it should look

http://play5star.com/test/index_no_background.html

Here's a link to in on the background image, as you can see the drop shadow changes to a bluish tint

http://play5star.com/test/index.html

Can someone tell me what they think is going on? Thanks for any help!

Comment: That happens because the shadow of your image is transparent.. So no, there is no CSS issue.

Answer (score 0):

The image http://play5star.com/test/KK-reg.png, has a drop shadow as you say. unfortunately it is not transparent, so it will always be grey no matter what background you have.

This has nothing to do with css, give the shadow opacity and it will work.